# Trigger macro when value changes with drop down selection

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

In excel I have a drop-down in f2  cell and when I change the drop-down selection the value in c10 changes

I want to create a macro which triggers every time the value in c10 changes,

How to achieve this.

This is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then
    
        MsgBox "C10 value changed!"

    End If

End Sub
```

But even when value changes the msgbox is not appearing or event is not triggering.
Kindly help me with this.

I want event to be triggered when cell value changes with the help of drop down selection.

Comment: Are you sure you put it into the Worksheet module where the events are defined? If you put it into a regular module it wont be connected to anything. It works just fine for me when I put it in the right place.

Comment: @braX yes it triggers when I change the value manually but when value changes with respect to change in drop-down selection, it won't trigger

Comment: You could additionally assign a macro to your dropdown: Sub DropDown1_Change()

   Range("c10").Value = Range("c10").Value
    
End Sub

Comment: If `C10` changes because there is a formula in it, you need `Worksheet Calculate` event. You will not be able to control which cell updates though. The event will trigger if any calculation happens. Now, if `C10` changes with `F2` then use `Worksheet Change` event but capture change in `F2` instead.

Comment: @l42 sorry I didn't get exactly what you are trying tell

Comment: Chance your target cell to `F2` is what L42 means, and should work

Comment: Form conrols do not fire a Worksheet_Change event, you have to use ActiveX conrol to manage changes